# Apple Mac will not see HTC Desire 620 via USB

Tags: usb

I have used HYC Sync manager previously but now both this software and double twist will not recognise my HTC Desire 620 when plugged in via USB.I have used both MTP and PTP settings on the phone but still the mac will not allow me to access it. Thoughts please!

Comment: And you also tried using a different USB cable?

Comment: Also try Google's solution for USB connections [here](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/).